# Exporting a collection of functions in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to Typescript and I've spent a while searching up various methods to do this, but I'm stuck.

I want to create a library file that just contains a collection of unrelated functions that I can import anywhere. In regular Javascript, I can just do something similar to this:

```
let libraryFunctions = {};
libraryFunctions.a = () => {
  return true;
}
module.exports = libraryFunctions;
```

However, in Typescript I just get a complaint saying `Property 'a' does not exist on type {}`. I then saw I could so something similar to this:

```
interface ILibraryFunctions {
  a(): boolean;
};

export class LibraryFunctions implements ILibraryFunctions {
  a = () => {
    return false;
  }
}
```

However, creating a class seems to be too excessive (unless if my understanding of Typescript's class is wrong). Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TypeScript, you just `export` whatever you want, similarly to ES2015 modules (which are also implemented by babel):

```
export function a() {
  return true;
}

// or alternatively

export const b = () => false
```

Then, in another file

```
import {a, b} from './thatFirstFile';
// or
import * as libraryFunctions from './thatFirstFile';
```

---

As for your specific scenario, you don't need to implement a class:

```
interface ILibraryFunctions {
  a(): boolean;
};

const myLib: ILibraryFunctions = {
  a() { return true; }
};

export default myLib;
```

That said, the method mentioned at the top of the answer is preferable, from [Daniel's comment below:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44478281/exporting-a-collection-of-functions-in-typescript/44478309?noredirect=1#comment75954038_44478309)

> Realistically, you wouldn't `export default` an object with `a`, you'd directly default-export `a` itself. That said, a reason you wouldn't do what was written is that existing tools can more-easily tree-shake from the top-level exports, but not from an actual object. Additionally, using the first syntax allows you to use ES2015's named import syntax when you have more than one export.

Comment: Thank you for your help! What's the reasoning behind why the first method is preferable?

Comment: Realistically, you wouldn't `export default` an object with `a`, you'd directly default-export `a` itself. That said, a reason you wouldn't do what was written is that existing tools can more-easily tree-shake from the top-level exports, but not from an actual object. Additionally, using the first syntax allows you to use ES2015's named import syntax when you have more than one export.

Comment: @DanielRosenwasser Thank you, this is an excellent point. I've added it to the answer for added visibility.